# how to debug lettuce tests in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, lettuce

I am new to lettuce framework and trying to find answer on how to debug lettuce tests ? Is it possible ? I found that PyCharm Professional Edition has BDD support.
I have got some existing tests written in lettuce. Can I debug them if I have got professional edition of pycharm ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

you may add breaking points to your test case and then `right click > debug` to debug your feature.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/run-debug-configuration-lettuce.html?origin=old_help